# How to specify an interface type to an object element in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to specify an interface to my object like this:

```js
interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}


var obj  = {
    name: "test",
    items:Item = null 
}
```

and I want to assign obj.items some value after I fetched some data from server on ngOninit().

is that possible?

Comment: `var obj: { name: string, items: Item | null } = { ... }`? Or you could use `items?: Item` and default to `undefined`, either implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Construction of Type**

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}

interface ParentItem {
    name: string;
    item: Item | null;
}
```

**Construction of Object:**

```
let object: ParentItem = { name: "test", item: null };
```

Comment: Despite the acceptance note that the construction example is neither: 1. valid syntax; nor 2. type safe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated the syntax, I am not sure to understand about type safety.

Comment: You say it is always an Item then set it to null. Either make it nullable or optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface ClientEmployee {
clientTeamID: number;
employeeID: number;
sharingPercent: number;
}
import 
 ClientEmployees = {
id: 0,
clientTeamID: 0,
employeeID: 0,
sharingPercent: 0,
clientName: ''
  };
 get in oninit 

 this.restService.GetTeamEmployees('').subscribe(response => {
  if (response.error == null && response.message === 'Success' && 
 response.data.length > 0) {
    this.ClientEmployees = response.data;
    this.loaderService.hide();
    }  });
```

Comment: What does this even mean?